# If we have two test classes with @MicronautTest then how many times the embedded server will be brought up?

Tags: micronaut

We have test code that looks like the one below with two test classes. Both having annotation as `@MicronautTest`.

```java
@MicronautTest
public class TestClass1
{
   @Inject
   EmbeddedServer embeddedServer;
}

@MicronautTest
public class TestClass2
{
   @Inject
   EmbeddedServer embeddedServer;
}
```

How many times `EmbeddedServer` will brought up?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Inject 
EmbeddedServer server
```

refers to the server that was started up for this test suite as per
[Documentation](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-test/latest/guide/index.html#junit5)